# Using MetadataContainer with ApexClassMember, ApexTrigger Member etc.

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api

I come to know that to update Apex component it is required to use `Metdatacontainer` object with ApexClassMember/ApexTrigger member. In Force.com Tooling API Dev guide given all examples to use `Metadatacontainer` and updating `ApexClassMember` and other *members*, but there all given examples uses `SOAP API`. In `REST API` only syntax and hints are provided for creating, deleting, describe but no implementation. I am able create a `Metadatcontainer` object and receive its `id` as response and by same way `ApexClassMember`, but don't know how to use it with `Metadatacontainer`.

My Question is how to include and work with `ApexClassMember` with `Metadatcontainer` or associating `ApexClassMember/ApexTriggerMember` with a `Metadacontainer` object using **REST API**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using Java, there are two blogs you can refer to and reference code which creates an [ApexClassMember](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexclassmember.htm) and set its **MetadataContainerId** property via the REST API.

- [New in Spring ’13: the Tooling API](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/01/new-in-spring-13-the-tooling-api.html)
- [Spring Cleaning Apex Code with the Tooling API](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/02/02/spring-cleaning-apex-code-with-the-tooling-api/)

Here is a code sample from first...

```
//First, the MetadataContainer
JSONObject metadataContainerRequest = new JSONObject();
metadataContainerRequest.put("Name", "SaveClass" + id); // Any unique name
JSONObject metadataContainerResponse = ToolingApi.post(
        "sobjects/MetadataContainer", metadataContainerRequest);
System.out.println("MetadataContainer id: "
        + metadataContainerResponse.get("id"));

// Then an ApexClassMember with our updated code
JSONObject apexClassMemberRequest = new JSONObject();
apexClassMemberRequest.put("MetadataContainerId",
        metadataContainerResponse.get("id"));
apexClassMemberRequest.put("ContentEntityId", id);
apexClassMemberRequest.put("Body", body);
JSONObject apexClassMemberResponse = ToolingApi.post(
        "sobjects/ApexClassMember", apexClassMemberRequest);
System.out.println("ApexClassMember id: "
        + apexClassMemberResponse.get("id"));
```

Or using POJO's (serialised to JSON) instead of the JSONObject class from the second...

```
MetadataContainer container = new MetadataContainer();
container.setName("UnusedApexMethods");
List saveResults = port.create(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(container)), sessionHeader);
String containerId = saveResults.get(0).getId();

ApexClassMember apexClassMember = new ApexClassMember();
apexClassMember.setBody(apexClass.getBody());
apexClassMember.setContentEntityId(apexClass.getId());
apexClassMember.setMetadataContainerId(containerId);
apexClassMembers.add(apexClassMember);
```

Comment: (+1) Basically I want to use Tooling API from the raw coding because my implementation is always language independent. I am able to create/delete tooling object but unable to update. Your answer is helpful to me. If you can provide reference for any article/blog where it is implemented from raw code in any language, then please share. Thanks @Andrew

Comment: I will try to help, can you explain what you mean by raw coding? Do you mean the actual JSON data representation?

Comment: Yes, I mean what mappings should be used to update a ApexTriggerMember or ApexClassMember. In mean while I was reading http://redcurrantscloud.blogspot.in/2013/09/forcecom-tooling-api-create-apex-class.html here details updating a apex class in Salesforce provided, but json mappings are creating confusion. If you can help in mappings of Json data than it will be very helpful to me. Thanks @Andrew

Comment: The two samples above map by name, its how they translate themselves to JSON internally, so when you see apexClassMemberRequest.put("MetadataContainerId", 'idvalue') or apexClassMember.setMetadataContainerId('idvalue') they will result in metadataContainerId : 'idvalue' being output.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understood, basically `apexClassMemberRequest.put("key", "value");` internally creates a json like {"key" : "value" } which is to be send in request body. Am I correct?

Comment: Yep thats basically how JSON serialisers work.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Now I have enough information. (Accepted)

Comment: Hi Anyone have create a post request with array of ApexClassMember using rest API